# Call Method from one package to another

Tags: android, function, methods, package, call

I am a beginner in this field.
How can i access a method from one package to another.

For example:

```
package add;

public class Addfunction {

    int a,b,sum;

    public int add(int x,int y)
    {
        a=x;
        b=y;
        sum=a+b;
        return sum;

    }
}
```

in my second package

```
package com.example.demoo;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        int Result;

        Addfunction addfunction=new Addfunction();
        Result=addfunction.add(5, 10);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }   
}
```

while running it shows Unfortunately app is stop.
please help me to solve this.

Comment: What about some code and logcat output? The question would be less broad with them :)

Comment: Please give me the correct syntax for accessing methods from one package to another.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong in how you access the `Addfunction` class. But consider two things.

First, you must add an import for the `Addfunction` class before the `MainActivity` class definition:

```
import add.Addfunction;
```

although you probably already have that, because it wouldn't compile otherwise.

Second, you are probably using this `makeText`:

> static Toast makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration) 
>       Make a standard toast that just contains a text view with the text from a resource.

instead of this:

> static Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration) 
>       Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.

Note the second parameter is an `int` in the first case which refers to a resource. And you are just passing the result of your computation which is probably an invalid resource id.

You may want to try to build a message in a `String` object and pass it to `makeText`, like this:

```
String msg = "Result: " + Result;
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```